# Convert std::string to v8::string and viceversa?

Tags: c++, node.js, string, casting, v8

i'm trying to create my first node module in c++. I just wanted to do a simple Hello  passing my name as parameter. I found this way to convert parameters to v8::strings which seems quite ugly:

```
Local<String> name = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, *v8::String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString()));
```

Is there anyone who could suggest me simple way to do this sort of cast?! Am i missing something?!

Comment: One simple solution would be to hide and encapculate this in some function.

Answer (score 6):

Newer versions of v8 requires also isolate:

```
void Foo(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args)
{
  // from v8 to cpp
  v8::Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  v8::String::Utf8Value str(isolate, args[0]);
  std::string cppStr(*str);

  // back to v8
  v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, cppStr.c_str(), v8::String::kNormalString);
}
```

Comment: for `//back to v8` I get error: `error: no member named 'kNormalString' in 'v8::String'`

Comment: Solved with cybafelo's solution

Answer (score 3):

For conversion to/from `std::string`, `NewFromUtf8` and `Utf8Value` are appropriate. For your example, however, the back-and-forth conversion is not necessary (and, in fact, is quite inefficient), you can simply do:

```
Local<String> name = args[0]->ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok I had a lot of trouble with this using node 12 and v8 7.4.288.

All the usual stuff has been deprecated so I fired up gdb to inspect the actual status quo.

So - I assume first you read the string from an Argument - a sensible way (the only way I could figure out from the docs and examples without too much pain) was this:

```
v8::Local<v8::String> fileName; 
fileName = args[0].As<v8::String>();
```

Right - now you have the 'string' in v8 format (as `v8::Local<v8::string>`)

To get access to the v8::string (and so that any current v8::String stuff is even slightly useful) - you need to de-reference the variable like this:

*fileName // this is now a v8::String - and you can use the functions like WriteUtf8 etc - the stuff you can do with it is documented here:

https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-12.0/d2/db3/classv8_1_1_string.html

You'll see the WriteUtf8 function expects isolate parameter and a char* buffer - I just guess my maximum string length here and create a quick char buffer to hold whatever I think will make sense:

```
char* charFileName = new char[8192];
```

Now I have enough space available to store some UTF 8 string - which I do by calling the WriteUtf8 function

```
(*fileName)->WriteUtf8(isolate, charFileName);
```

Finally - I had already defined my std::string elsewhere (in global scope) like this

```
static std::string stringFileName;
```

So - to get the data from the char* into my std::string I do this:

```
stringFileName.assign(charFileName);
```

You can also do it by calling the std::string constructor if you like and passing the char* to it in the constructor.

And I delete my original char* to clean up since its not needed anymore - the std::string will cleanup after itself when it goes out of scope - I don't know how v8 cleans up after itself and honestly i don't care.

```
delete charFileName;
```

Finally - v8::String string into a usable std::string - today (in 2020)

Also - if you want to now convert between std::string and V8::String you'd probably do something similar- convert the `std::string` to `char*`, create a `<v8::Local<v8::String>>`, dereference it `(*mylocalv8string)` and call `NewFromUtf8 (isolate, char*)` on that dereferenced localv8string

Comment: Here's how I converted from type char*  to type v8::Local<v8::String) in 2020 for a return value in node v13: `v8::Local<v8::String> result; v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> temp = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, jsonOutput); temp.ToLocal(&result); args.GetReturnValue().Set(result);`

Answer (score 2):

## Node > **v13**

Here's how I converted from type char* to type

```cpp
v8::Local<v8::String>
```

in **2020** for a return value in node > **v13**:

```cpp
v8::Isolate *isolate = info.GetIsolate();
auto context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
v8::Local<v8::String> result; 
v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> temp = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, jsonOutput);
temp.ToLocal(&result); 
args.GetReturnValue().Set(result);
```

Comment: For me, this version still triggers a deprecation warning in node@12.16.2. If you add NewStringType::kNormal as a parameter to NewFromUtf8, it goes away:

`String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, matrixJson.dump().c_str(), NewStringType::kNormal);`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create wrappers for this. You also have to check your local handle `name`, if it is not empty. Newer implementations uses the MaybeLocal handle to ensure that any result has been checked.

Some examples what i have done:

```
/* Tool: JS execution has been terminated. */
class TerminateEx : public exception {
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    { return "JSBaseClass: Execution terminated"; };
};

/* Tool: Convert MaybeLocal<> to Local<>
 * Throws TerminateEx if the handle is empty (JS execution has been
 * terminated).
 */
template<typename C>
inline v8::Local<C>
JSBaseClass::toLocalHandle(v8::MaybeLocal<C> handle)
{
    if (handle.IsEmpty())
        throw TerminateEx();
    return handle.ToLocalChecked();
}

/* Tool: Create JS string*/
inline
v8::Local<v8::String>
JSBaseClass::newJSString(v8::Isolate *isolate, const char *str)
{
    return (toLocalHandle(
                v8::String::NewFromUtf8(
                    isolate, str, v8::NewStringType::kNormal)));
};

/* Tool: Create JS string*/
inline
v8::Local<v8::String>
JSBaseClass::newJSString(v8::Isolate *isolate, const string &str)
{
    return newJSString(isolate, str.c_str());
};

/* Tool: Create JS string*/
template<typename T>
inline v8::Local<v8::String>
JSBaseClass::newJSString(const T &info, const string &str)
{
    return newJSString(info.GetIsolate(), str.c_str());
};

[...]

/* Tool: Throw JS exception */
template<typename T> inline void
JSBaseClass::throwJSError(const T &info, const string &text)
{
    info.GetIsolate()->ThrowException(
        v8::Exception::Error(newJSString(info, text.c_str())));
    info.GetReturnValue().SetUndefined();
    return;
};

[...]

/* Tool: Get string from JS value. returns false if the conversion failed. */
inline bool
JSBaseClass::valueToString(
    const v8::Local<v8::Context> &context,
    const v8::Local<v8::Value> &value,
    string *str)
{
    v8::String::Utf8Value utf8Str(
        toLocalHandle(value->ToString(context)));
    if (!*utf8Str)
        return false;

    *str = *utf8Str;
    return true;
}
```

And then use it this like this:

```
try {
    auto isolate = info.GetIsolate();
    auto context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();

    Local<Value> name = JSBaseClass::newJSString(info, "My Name");

    [...]

    string nameStr;

    if (!JSBaseClass::valueToString(context, name, &nameStr)) {
        JSBaseClass::throwJSError(info, "Not a string");
        return;
    }
    [...]
}
catch (JSBaseClass::TemplateEx) {
    return;
}
```

I you use a newer version of V8 you should avoid the deprecated methods. The current methods mostly return `MaybeLocal<>` handles.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this method as well

```
    void StringConversion(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args){
        Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate(); // isolate will isolate the whole process in new memory space; so that no other thread can make change onto it at the same time 
        v8::String::Utf8Value s(args[0]); // take the string arg and convert it to v8::string
        std::string str(*s); // take the v8::string convert it to c++ class string
        //convert back the **str** to v8::String, so that we can set and return it 
        Local<String> result= String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,str.c_str()); // c_str() will return a pointer to an array that contain null-terminator sequence  
        args.GetReturnValue().Set(result);
    }
```

Thanks !!

Comment: For setting result, `error: no viable conversion from 'MaybeLocal<v8::String>' to 'v8::Local<v8::String>'` EDIT: solved with cybafelo's solution

Comment: This MaybeLocal handle needs to be resolved to a Local handle by calling 'ToLocalChecked()'. If it is 'empty' and contains nothing you will get a runtime error, otherwise, it will be resolved to a local handle.