# Converting v8 args to std::string

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

My goal is to run a function in Node.js and provide a string as parameter/argument:

```
const myAddon = require('path'); myAddon.myFunc(otherData, "Hello World");
```

What I've tried, according to a Stack Overflow answer, was the following:

```
v8::String::Utf8Value STR_ARG(args[1]->ToString());
std::string USER_MESSAGE = std::string(*STR_ARG);
```

This didn't work and I got this error Message:

> ToString Function doesn't accept 0 Arguments.

Am I supposed to give the function any input and if so, what?

Comment: There is [documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-14.1/dc/d0a/classv8_1_1_value.html#a0ae37e4f530290ab2c6b47bb9894626a) for v8 that tells you you need a Context, which you can get from [the Isolate passed to your function](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-14.1/d5/dda/classv8_1_1_isolate.html#a81c7a1ed7001ae2a65e89107f75fd053)

Comment: Don't just copy/paste from Stack Overflow: read and study the documentation!

Comment: @Botje you are my Hero, answered both of my Question :D tysm

Answer (score 0):

The Solution I tried to approach in my Question didnt work properly. If it doesnt work for you either, here is the Code that Worked for me.

```
        v8::Local<v8::String> argsINPUT;
        argsINPUT = args[0].As<v8::String>();
//Having a Second Argument to determine the Buffer Size is Optional but Optimal
//new char[insert any int] is also okay, but it should be large enough to hold the Data
        char* args_buffer = new char[args[1].As<Number>()->Value()];
//If the Next Line thows an Error try out '(argsINPUT*)' instead of 'argsINPUT'
        argsINPUT->WriteUtf8(isolate, args_buffer);

        static std::string finalString;
        finalString.assign(args_buffer);

        delete args_buffer;

        args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(
            isolate, finalString.c_str()).ToLocalChecked());
```

Credits to Cybafelo:

[Convert std::string to v8::string and viceversa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113427/convert-stdstring-to-v8string-and-viceversa?rq=1)

And Botje for helping me out with my Original Approach

**Edit:** Reason why `args[1].As<Number>()->Value()` might be optimal as Buffer Size:

js code example:

```
const myAddon = require('path');

const myString = "Hello World";
myAddon.myFunc(myString, myString.length + 1);
```

As you can see and probably know, Js provides us with properties and functions, one of them is the length Property, so we can just Directly create a perfectly size Buffer. The +1 is at the end because Im not sure if we need also space for "\0"