# Cannot convert 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Value>'

Tags: c++, node.js, casting, electron, v8

I'm trying to upgrade a working Electron app from 5 to 6 which has introduced a breaking change...

```
error C2664: 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>,uint32_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Value>'
```

...compiling the following code.

```
  Isolate* isolate = info.GetIsolate();

  Local<Object> group = Local<Object>::Cast(info[0]);
  Local<Array> A = Local<Array>::Cast(group->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,"A"))); <<-- Error here
  Local<Array> B = Local<Array>::Cast(group->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,"B"))); << Same error here
```

[Erroring lines are e.g. 113/114 in this file if more context would help](https://github.com/Jack000/Deepnest/blob/master/minkowski.cc)

I've found [some suggestions, e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113427/convert-stdstring-to-v8string-and-viceversa) that probably come close but C++ is totally alien to me and I've spent too long trying to do this already. I expect the fix will be really easy to someone who knows C++ and it'll be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Got it. Suffix each with `.ToLocalChecked()`

e.g. `Local<Array> A = Local<Array>::Cast(group->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,"A").ToLocalChecked()));`

Comment: Bumping Electron 6 to 7 required additionally: `Local<Array> A = Local<Array>::Cast(group->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,"A",v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked()));`

Answer (score 4):

(V8 developer here.)

The background is that **`MaybeLocal`s are returned by functions that can fail**, in particular: that can throw an exception. That includes pretty much everything that involves JavaScript execution, including setting or reading properties to/from JS objects (getters, setters, Proxies, read-only properties/objects can all throw), most conversions (anything involving `.valueOf` or `.toString`, also BigInt-to-Number or Symbol-to-String or vice versa, ...), etc.

The idea behind `MaybeLocal` is to make this explicit, so as an embedder of V8 you can be sure that your code is robust towards such JavaScript shenanigans. Generally, you should check whether a `MaybeLocal` `IsEmpty()`, and if so, handle that error case. As a convenience, there's the conditional conversion to `Local`:

```
Local<Value> value;
MaybeLocal<Value> maybe_value = FunctionThatCanThrowAnException();
if (!maybe_value.ToLocal(&value)) {
  // No value was returned. If you have a `v8::TryCatch`, it should have
  // caught an exception. Handle that somehow, and return early.
}
// Otherwise: everything's good, continue with `value`.
```

If you simply use `.ToLocalChecked()`, you're saying: assume that this `MaybeLocal` is, in fact, a `Local`, and crash otherwise. That may be appropriate (when you can guarantee that a particular operation couldn't possibly have thrown an exception), but if you just slap these on everywhere, chances are you'll see crashes when something throws that you didn't anticipate.

Allocating a new short string such as `"A"` is going to be fine (the only way it can fail is OOM, in which case the whole process is killed anyway); but as soon as your input string is user-controlled (and hence could be arbitrarily large), the allocation attempt could throw a `RangeError`.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. I really wasn't proud of the blanket application but hasn't caused issues. I'm not changing anything that didn't work before, just being forced to upgrade it via dependencies so a little crossed fingers going on; and has seemed to be so far; touch wood! I've not had to jump back in to it but will follow the offered advice when I get back to it. MTIA again.